# FaceBook Comments plugin help

Tags: facebook

I am trying to use the facebook comments plugins in my website.
so I added the plugin in every article.
but the comments are the same, for example if i wrote a comment in article a,
it appears also in article b.

did anyone know how to work with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set the xid unique for each article; all comments with the same xid will appear together

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ASP.Net then you could always set the `href` attribute of the `fb:comments` tag to be the same url as that of your page. This ensures unique comment maintainability across different pages (articles). I have included the implementation that I used on www.myPUBGUIDE.com below:

```
<fb:comments href="<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri %>" num_posts="10" width="500"></fb:comments>
```