# Facebook comments plugin on multiple pages?

Tags: html, facebook, plugins, comments

I have a website with multiple pages. It's a news-related site that generates article pages with unique URLs, like http://localhost:5000/results/167 and http://localhost:5000/results/168. I want to use the [Facebook comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments), but I can't figure out how to get it to keep comments on different pages separate --- they all just get lumped in together, no matter what page someone comments on. What do I do?

Someone else [asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450547/facebook-comments-plugin-help) a few years ago, but I couldn't understand the answer — they said to "set the xid unique for each article," I wasn't sure what that meant (I'm new).

Many thanks! My HTML code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v5.0&appId=1560520617436290&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://localhost:5000/results/" data-width="" data-numposts="5"></div>
<br>
    <div class="voteorresult"><a href="/votefor/{{ 'id' }}">Vote</a></div>
<a href="/">
    <div class="home">
        Investigate more articles
    </div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it working! I added jinja to the URL:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://localhost:5000/results/{{ id }}" data-width="" data-numposts="5"></div>
```